# Why do I get this exception?

Tags: debugging

I'm getting this error constantly and I can't quite figure out what's wrong.

> TypeError: strpos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, array given in strpos() (line 126 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/Dependency.php).
> strpos(Array, ':') (Line: 126)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\Dependency::createFromString(Array) (Line: 228)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->buildModuleDependencies(Array) (Line: 169)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleExtensionList->doList() (Line: 282)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList->getList() (Line: 143)
> Drupal\update\UpdateManager->getProjects() (Line: 283)
> update_get_available() (Line: 38)
> update_requirements('runtime') (Line: 96)
> update_page_top(Array) (Line: 356)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent{closure}(Object, 'update') (Line: 405)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAllWith('page_top', Object) (Line: 357)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->buildPageTopAndBottom(Array) (Line: 150)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object) call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 142)
> Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch(Object, 'kernel.view') (Line: 174)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 81)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 718)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by an incorrect *.info.yml file.

A correct example would be:

*media.info.yml*

```
name: Media
description: 'Manages the creation, configuration, and display of media items.'
type: module
package: Core
version: VERSION
dependencies:
  - drupal:file
  - drupal:image
  - drupal:user
configure: media.settings
```

Where you can see that in `dependencies` each value is a string. You have installed a module where the *.info.yml file contains a subarray instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I followed this but am now presented with a new error Error message

Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for sites/default/files/php/twig/64b0f0e5da6a4_block--local-actions-bloc_ehGUpffeW4WztV4yt3YIIFTYB/rdxaXvhzA2APVyhQiNk7E9DqdFVi_RFtckjlJqdY0M0.php in Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\MTimeProtectedFileStorage->checkFile() (line 63 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/PhpStorage/MTimeProtectedFileStorage.php).

Comment: It's only a warning, Can you remove it by clearing the cache? If not, ask a new question and add more details about when this is happening and what you have tried so far.